# Password for database in chinese

Tags: ms-access

I would like to migrate the data from a MS-Access database to another software but the database is protected with password. I have used Access Password Unlocker to explore the password but I get chinese (or other languaje) characters as you can see in the image.

How can I write this characters??

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: I can not copy with this software. Thanks

Comment: yikes, that's not very clever on the part of the app designer then. I use pseudo-random passwords myself, and would kill myself if my password manager doesn't let me copy and paste... could you try OCR-ing the text with, say, Google Goggles on a smartphone?

Comment: @michel-slm I have used Access Password Unlocker

Comment: See the screenshot on the link I gave - there it clearly shows that when it found the password you are prompted to press the Copy button. You might have an older version, or somehow couldn't trigger the modal dialog that has the copy button?

Answer (score 1):

The current version of Access Password Unlocker [seems to allow you to copy](http://www.passwordunlocker.com/guide/access-password-recovery.html) the retrieved password, any chance you could use it?

Answer (score 0):

偊佈久埼

Is this it? If you can post a higher resolution image of the Chinese characters, I can try again.